# PostgreSQL accessing nested uppercased properties

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've recently switched from mongoDB to postgreSQL and for a while I got stuck with this problem - I can't seem to find a way to access nested property of an object. Yes, I shouldn't be having uppercased column/table names to start with, but I really want to keep naming consistency.

Let's say I have the following db table:

```sql
users {
    ID: bigint
}
```

Now let's say I want to get deleted user(old) ID, how do I access this ID?

```sql
    create or replace function deleted()
        returns trigger AS

        $body$
            begin
                perform pg_notify('deleted', ----->WHAT GOES HERE<-----);

                return new;
            end;
        $body$
```

I've tried filling in placeholder with `old."ID"`, then I get following error:

```
ERROR:  function pg_notify(unknown, bigint) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_notify('deleted', old."ID")
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT pg_notify('deleted', old."ID")
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function deleted() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL state: 42883
```

If I try doing this -> `old.ID` then I get

```
ERROR:  record "old" has no field "id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT pg_notify('deleted', old.ID)"
PL/pgSQL function deleted() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL state: 42703
```

Also I've tried this: `"old.ID", then I get the following:

```
ERROR:  column "old.ID" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_notify('deleted', "old.ID")
                                          ^
QUERY:  SELECT pg_notify('deleted', "old.ID")
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function deleted() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL state: 42703
```

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Delete triggers do not have a NEW record.  Just the OLD (deleted one).  You should also return OLD, not NEW as in insert and update triggers.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson noted and fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pg_notify()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) wants two arguments of `text` datatype. So you can cast your `bigint` argument to that datatype:

```
pg_notify('deleted', (old."ID")::text)
```